# How to access the user specified --prefix value in the postinstallation script during RPM installation?

Tags: rpm

I have created a rpm package with a post-install script using the prefix value /usr/local. When i install the rpm with the --prefix=/tmp/mylocation the script execution fails to looks for a file under the new location.

%post 
mv /usr/local/PACKAGE/file /etc

Using the %{prefix} in the script also doesn't works(mv %{prefix}/PACKAGE/file /etc).

Answer (score 5):

In case, anybody else wants to know,Using $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access the real prefix in scriptlets with $RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX, but there is usually no reason to use it if your RPM is created correctly.

If you *really* know what you are doing then mucking around with scriptlets (%post/%postun code) is OK. However note that all RPM macros are expanded during build time. Ergo things like:

```
%post
echo %{_prefix}
```

Would always expand to `echo /usr`. You can actually look at the scriptlets inside generated RPMs to see how they look expanded. That said...

From the short snippet it seems you are doing the installation incorrectly. Copying/moving files is not normally done in %post/%postun scriptlets. Those run on user's system (usually as root) and it's quite easy to make a devastating mistake completely destroying user's system.

So a somewhat valid snippet:

```
SourceX: <config_file>
...
%install
...
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}
cp %{SOURCEX} %{buildroot}%{sysconfdir}
...


%files
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/<config_file>
...
```

As an another side note, installation into /usr/local is generally frowned upon (unless you are creating RPMs for your own use).

Comment: Why must all the RPM'ers out there insist that everything must be a Linux package and installed into /usr/bin? Whatever happened /opt? /opt was a valid installation directory for vendor software. /usr/local should be fine. And what if your trying to package some embedded software that must be installed in a specific file share like /tftpboot? I know Redhat started RPMs. At one point it became a very useful generic package manager, now it seems to be leaning very specifically to Linux Distro only and becoming much more difficult to use a generic package manager. Such a disappointment.